# How to make the primary in the replica set to become unavailable in order to hold an election?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I created a replica set with three members.
now I read the following link: [Replica Set Elections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)
which explains only in an abstract way what is going on.

So they say that when the primary becomes unavailable the elections occur.
So I was trying to make the primary unavailable by <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> in the terminal which holds the mongod instance, the other two secondaries were sending each other heartbeats to connect but I got in each terminal:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.1.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
```

So maybe that's not the way to make the primary unavailable?

Can you help me please, I cant find examples..

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the replica set configured properly?  The IP address 127.0.1.1 should be 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Did you mean in the file mongodb.conf? I have the bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

Comment: You must have mistyped the IP address given in the error message then. How do you know one of the secondaries didn't become primary?  Did you change the priority of the secondaries to 0?  Are the secondaries actual nodes or arbiters?

Comment: I copy paste the error from the terminal of one of the secondaries, the same error appear in the other secondary. I get this error every 2 sec [ReplExecNetThread-0] Failed to connect to 127.0.1.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused

[ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to nurith-Lenovo-Y50-70-Touch:27017; Location18915 Failed attempt to connect to nurith-Lenovo-Y50-70-Touch:27017; couldn't connect to server nurith-Lenovo-Y50-70-Touch:27017 (127.0.1.1), connection attempt failed.       I didn't change the priority, they all have priority 1, the secondaries are actual nodes.

Comment: You must have something misconfigured then because your error message shows the secondary is trying to connect to an invalid IP address.  I have a development replica set with all nodes running on the same machine. I don't specify the bind_ip for any of the nodes, only the port.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest option provided by Mongo is,

```
rs.stepdown()
```

Use this function on primary replica to make it unavailable for specified period of time. This causes other members to reelect new primary.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turns out that Ubuntu had the FQDN set to `127.0.1.1` in `/etc/hosts`.

Either make `mongod` listen on `127.0.1.1` or edit `/etc/hosts` to remove the `127.0.1.1` entry or change it to `127.0.0.1.`

This resolved my issue.